# How do I get a specific file from a GZIP in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, gzip

I need to get a specfic CSV file from a GZIP. So far I have:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('my-files.zip') as myzip:
        with myzip.open('my-doc.csv') as myfile:
            reader = csv.reader(myfile)
```

This throws an error though:

```
AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'open'
```

I was using the zipfile module but the zip would not open:

```
$ file  my-files.zip
my-files.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

The file can be found at: http://www.rivcoeh.org/yelp

Comment: Gzip is for compressing / decompressing single files, it doesn't know about archives. On a *nix system it's common to use tar to handle the archiving, and then use a compressor like gzip or bzip on the resulting archive file. What error message do you get if you pass `my-files.zip` to a command-line unzip utility?

Comment: I don't get an error using the command-line (Terminal on Mac) unzip utility... curious.

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing zip and gzip?

Comment: Nope. I was using the zipfile module but kept getting `raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"` errors. So I tried GZIP which didn't throw any errors but alas I can't use it because it doesn't handle archives.

Comment: I've never had a problem with the `zipfile` module, but I normally use it on well-behaved zipfiles, like .epub files. Do you have any control over the creation of these zipfiles? I guess if all else fails you could use the `subprocess` module to call the command-line unzipper.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://bugs.python.org/issue24621

Comment: There are multiple kinds of zip files that are valid, but can't be handled by the `zipfile` module, or can only be handled by passing non-default options. Without knowing anything about your zip file, it's hard to guess which one it is, but one very common one is that it's a ZIP64. That option was off by default until common *nix command-line tools started handling it by default, after which Python changed it to match. But if you're still using 2.7, that's from before that change.

Comment: Also, IIRC, the Mac `unzip` tool isn't the Info-ZIP one, but one of the alternatives that silently handles a bunch of similar but incompatible formats—but `zipinfo` and/or `file` should be able to tell you if that's what's going on.

Comment: If you can add the output of `file my-files.zip` to your question, and…  `zipinfo -v my-files.zip` is probably way too much, but maybe put the header and main dir record here, and link to the whole thing on a gist? Also, if the zipfile isn't too large and doesn't have anything private in it, maybe share that somewhere? (No guarantee anyone will want to download it and examine it, but someone might.)

Comment: OK, lets stop second-guessing here. You've got Mac; please execute `file my-files.zip` and copy the output thereof into the question itself.

Comment: And since a GZIP format cannot accommodate multiple files, the answer to the question title is "you don't".

Answer (score 1):

gzip and zip are two entirely different things. You can't use the gzip class to open a zip file.